# Magento 2.1.8 Uncaught TypeError: data.some is not a function

Tags: magento

I am stuck while adding new customer from admin. I get data.some js error. Due to this error, loader keeps on loading due to which not able to add new customer from admin.

If someone can help me out in this, it will be great. Thanks in advance

Comment: can you provide error screen-sort or description what the real error?

Comment: There was some method missing, but adding a patch helped me out in Magento_Ui/view/base/web/js/form/element/select.js in findFirst function

Comment: can you please post this patch. And how to apply that patch? i am getting same error and not able to add product

Comment: Following this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/193761/magento-2-typeerror-data-some-is-not-a-function/200371#200371 has helped to solve my issue.